# Multilingual Support in Forms 6i

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

I have a requirement regarding oracle form 6i. I have a tabular data block in form 6i and I want the table headers to be changed based on user login credentials, for example if user logs in using Arabic then table headers should dynamically change to Arabic or if user log in using English then table headers should change dynamically to English and so on.

Basically the language of column headers should change/set dynamically.

If you have achieved this then please help me in this regard.

I am using form 6i and database version is 10g.

Thanks and Regard,
Laxya

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not easily done. If you wish the column headings in Forms to be dynamic then the headings need to be painted as display fields and linked to a metadata table that stores the column names in the languages you want to support. In other words you need to store the column names and whatever else you need to display e.g. screen messages in tables to be retrieved at runtime and shown on the screen based on a runtime parameter passed into the screen e.g. LANGCODE = ENG for English or ARB for Arabic

Example of a metadata table:

```
LANGCODE  FORMNAME  TABLENAME  COLUMNNAME  COLUMNNAME_TO_DISPLAY
--------  --------  ---------  ----------  ---------------------
ENG       ABC123    TABLEA     COLUMN1     COLUMN1
ENG       ABC123    TABLEA     COLUMN2     COLUMN2
ARB       ABC123    TABLEA     COLUMN2     ???????
ARB       ABC123    TABLEA     COLUMN2     ???????
```

You would simply enter the value you want to display in the screen in the last column in the table above in whatever language that the backend database supports.

Note that while this allows the screen to have headings and fieldnames that are dynamically fetched at runtime in a when-new-form-instance trigger, they add a lot of extra maintenance effort since everything that is displayed on the screen needs to be mapped to a table somewhere. This is why you will find very few forms applications that are truly multi-lingual.

Comment: You do not need to set the column headings as display fields.  You can use `SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('BLOCK.FIELD', PROMPT_TEXT, 'New Prompt Value')`.